# Which type of form to use for creating a Subform in MS-Access 2010 that displays a running progress report to the user?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform

My form has a button "Process files", and when pressed, nested VBA procedures will be executed and a subform will display a table of ids and their associated results.  My question is in order to display a table  with mutliple rows in a format that resembles something similar to a datasheet do I create the subform with the Multiple Items Form or the Datasheet form.   Some more specifications on the subform are:

Form Properties
Name: fsubInstrumentInterfaceLog; Default View: Continuous; Record Selectors: Yes; Navigation Buttons: Yes; Scrollbars: Vertical
Header, Detail, Footer
Header: Column headings
Detail: One row of data fields. fields set to Enabled = Yes; Locked = Yes. 
Container Properties
Insert this form into frmInstrumentInterface with Subform/Subreport control
Parent-Child Link: Link Master Fields: BatchID, cboInstrument; Link Child Fields: BatchID, InstrumentName
Special Effect: Etched

Comment: What are you trying to do? If its just popping open a table, then why are you posting the subform-specs? What is the MultipleItemsForm?

Comment: I want to display a table of the results in the subform which will be on the bigger form.In Access 2010, under the create tab there is a drop down menu button called More Forms, the first two forms are Database and mutiple items which are two types of forms.  I am trying to figure out which form if either would better display my table of results within my subform.

Comment: ...then I dont see where your question leads to. Use whichever you like more. (You can later change it anyway by changing the view. The functionality is more or less the same. If you have a very specific requirement it may be that one or the other is better - but then you would have to post those specific requirements in order for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my thoughts between both styles of continuous forms.

**Datasheets forms**

- Resemble Access tables and Excel spreadsheets.
- Can be very wide or long with no limit (to my knowledge).
- Individual rows and columns width and height dimensions are adjustable by user (not limited to designer).
- Does not contain editable form headers/footers. However, datasheets do allow footer aggregates (Sum, Avg, Count, etc.)
- Conditional formatting can be applied.
- All trigger events by field controls can be applied.
- Limited GUI objects and their events can be integrated (no labels, buttons, or list boxes, etc.). Combo boxes can be added though. But this may not matter if you use a main form.
- Special effects, back color, border color, and other control designs not allowed.
- Controls can be locked from user changes.
- Record selectors highlight entire row like spreadsheet.
- Navigation controls and scrollbars are enabled.
- Parent-Child links can be established like any other subform/subreport.

**Multiple item forms**

- Resembles a row by row form view of the data.
- Limited to 22 inches in width and height.
- Individual row and columns width and height dimensions are not adjustable by user but limited to designer.
- Does contain editable form header/footer.
- Conditional formatting can be applied.
- All trigger events by field names can be applied.
- Any GUI objects and their events can be integrated (labels, buttons, drop down fields, etc.). But this may not matter if you use a main form.
- Special effects, back color, border color, and other control designs are enabled.
- Controls can be locked from user changes.
- Record selector limited to arrow at far left of record.
- Navigation controls and scrollbars are enabled.
- Parent-Child links can be established like any other subform/subreport.

Overall, both operate very similarly. For me the choice depends on functionality of your form and subform combination. Multiple item forms provide a more natural user interface that be consistent with other forms. Datasheets can disrupt such a UI but they are easy setup for large volume.